# Correlation matrix of categorical and numerical values not working

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to convert my categorical columns into integers with Label Encoder in order to create a correlation matrix consisting of a mix of numerical and categorical variables. This is my table structure:

```
a   int64
b   int64
c   object
d   object
e   object
f   object
g   object
dtype: object

from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
for x in df.columns:
    if df[x].dtypes=='object':
       df[x]=le.fit_transform(df[x])
corr = df.corr()
```

Then I get this error:

```
TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-205607> in <module>()
      3 for x in df.columns:
      4     if df[x].dtypes=='object':
----> 5        df[x]=le.fit_transform(df[x])
      6 corr = df.corr()

/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py in fit_transform(self, y)
    129         y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
    130         _check_numpy_unicode_bug(y)
--> 131         self.classes_, y = np.unique(y, return_inverse=True)
    132         return y
    133 

/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py in unique(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts, axis)
    221     ar = np.asanyarray(ar)
    222     if axis is None:
--> 223         return _unique1d(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts)
    224     if not (-ar.ndim <= axis < ar.ndim):
    225         raise ValueError('Invalid axis kwarg specified for unique')

/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py in _unique1d(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts)
    278 
    279     if optional_indices:
--> 280         perm = ar.argsort(kind='mergesort' if return_index else 'quicksort')
    281         aux = ar[perm]
    282     else:

TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()
```

Does anybody have an idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change     `df[x]=le.fit_transform(df[x])` to

> df[x]=le.fit_transform(df[x].astype(str))

And it should work.